# Stochastic continuity of a random process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $\xi = (\xi_t,t ∈ [0,1])$ be a random process such that all $xi_t, t ∈ T$, are independent in the aggregate, equally distributed and non-trivial (different from constant). Is the process $xi$ stochastically continuous at a single point $[0,1]$?
Stochastic continuity in point $t_0$ means that $\xi_t \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\to} \xi_{t_0}, t \rightarrow t_0$

Random variables are called independent in the aggregate if for any set of Borel sets $B_{t_1}, ..., B_{t_n} \in \mathbb{B(\mathbb{R})}$
$$
\mathbb{P}(\xi_{t_1} \in B_{t_1}, ..., \xi_{t_n} \in B_{t_n}) = \mathbb{P}(\xi_{t_1} \in B_{t_1})  ...\mathbb{P}(\xi_{t_n} \in B_{t_n}) 
$$

I would be grateful for any hint, since I don't understand how to even approach the problem.

Comment: Use `$\xi$` for $\xi$.

Comment: @Shaun edited my question

Comment: I would use that convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence of a subsequence. Then I would find $x<y$ such that $\mathbb P(\xi_0<x)$ and $\mathbb P(\xi_0>y)$ are positive, and justify by the Borel-Cantelli lemma that the aforementioned subsequence has infinitely many terms above $y$, and infinitely many under $x$, hence it cannot almost surely converge.

Comment: @Will But if sequence does not converge almost surely, it will not imply that sequence will not converge in probability

Comment: As I said, convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence of a subsequence. So if $\xi_t$ converges in probability to $\xi_{t_0}$, then you can find a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge1}$ which converges to $t_0$ such that $\xi_{t_n}$ converges almost surely to $\xi_{t_0}$. Then you can apply for instance my argument above to justifify that $\xi_{t_n}$ does not converge almost surely, which yields a contradiction.

Comment: There are probably much easier ways to solve it though, it was just the first idea I had in mind. An alternative for example would be to consider $x<y$ such that $\mathbb P(\xi_{t_0}<x)$ and $\mathbb P(\xi_{t_0}>y)$ are positive. Then for $\varepsilon=y-x$ you have that $\mathbb P(\vert\xi_t-\xi_{t_0}\vert>\varepsilon)\ge\mathbb P(\xi_{t_0}<x,\xi_t>y)=\mathbb P(\xi_{t_0}<x)\mathbb P(\xi_{t_0}>y)$ so it does not vanish.

Comment: @Will I understood the idea, but i don't understand why $\mathbb{P}(|\xi_{t} - \xi_{t_0}| > \epsilon) \geq \mathbb{P}(\xi_{t_0} < x,  \xi_{t_0} > y)$?

Comment: Because if $\xi_t>y$ and $\xi_{t_0}<x$ then $\xi_t-\xi_{t_0}>y-x=\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Will I got it, thank you!